# How to curl --upload-file in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, curl

Hi I have a server in Node who catch the request, when I use

```
curl --upload-file myFile.jpeg http://myhost.com/upload
```

All is going well, but when I do that request in angular, the server returns a 400 even if I haven't defined that behavior on the server. I only know that curl --upload-file uses a HTTP PUT to send the data.

This is my Angular service

```
angular.module('myApp')
.factory('UploadService',function($http){
  var service = {}
  service.uploadFile = function(path){
    return $http.put('http://myhost.com/upload','/home/myFile.jpeg')
 }
  return service;
})
```

I'm sure that I'm missing some headers, but I can't found documentation about what curl --file-upload does under the hood.

How is the way to do that request? and why Node sends a 400 if I haven't defined that response?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You probably need to specify the content type for image. 400 means invalid data for your request